# MaskedEditExtender mask not showing

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I was playing around with ASP.NET AjaxControlToolkit and trying to add a `MaskedEditExtender` to a `asp:TextBox`

This is my code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender
                                        ID="meDOB1"
                                        TargetControlID="txtDOB1" 
                                        Mask="99/LLL/9999"
                                        MaskType="None"
                                        InputDirection="LeftToRight"
                                        OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus" 
                                        runat="server" PromptCharacter="_"     UserDateFormat="DayMonthYear"/>
```

I was expecting the `TextBox` to have a mask that looks like `__/___/____` but nothing appears in the `TextBox`. Absolutely clueless here!

Comment: Are extender and target textbox placed in common naming container?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy if Common Naming Containers mean that the ID of the target textbox or the extender not being changed as `ct100_txtDOB1` etc then yes - they are in the common naming containers.

Comment: Show more markup? including target texbox. Is there any error message in browser's console?